# React hooks reference values comparison

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

everyone!
Imagine, I have a component SomeComponent. Every time 'b' value changes, useEffect is triggering despite 'b is not in its dependencies

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const a = [1, 2, 3] //just an example of dependency. In real life it will be a changing value
  const b = useSelector(someValueSelector)

  useEffect(() => {
    //do some staff
  }, [a])
}
```

Is there any way to store reference to 'a' array inside of SomeComponent? The only way I know is to create a wrapper component and pass

```
a = useMemo(() => [1, 2, 3], [])
```

as a props to

```
<SomeComponent a={a} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that on every re-render a's reference changes and hence the `useEffect` is triggered again

You can make use of `useMemo` inside `SomeComponent`  to assign a memoized value to `a`

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const a = useMemo(() => [1, 2, 3], []); 
  const b = useSelector(someValueSelector)

  useEffect(() => {
    //do some staff
  }, [a])
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
Is there a possibility to combine this with a function that depends on some state (redux for example)?

Comment: Could you elaborate on it please, so that I can update my post with more finer details. As of now I am only working with what you have provided

Comment: Oh, I found a solution, typing to you )) Thank you again!

Comment: I am guessing that has to do with calling the function inside useMemo with the appropriate dependency. Good that your issue is resolved :-) Glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

As you may have gathered, but to be explicit for any future readers, this is due to object equality in JavaScript. Since objects are compared by reference, `{} === {}` evaluates to `false`.

Depending on your use case, you can work around this in the following ways:

1. If the values are static and not dependent on props, define `a` in the same scope as the component. This removes the need to declare it as a dependency for the `useEffect` routine:

   ```
   const a = [1, 2, 3]
   const SomeComponent = () => {
     useEffect(() => {
       // do something with `a`
     }, [])
   }
   ```
2. If the value is dynamic but changes should not cause the component to re-render, use a ref. Changing the value of the ref will not prompt React to re-render the component and the same object will be returned from `useRef()` on each render:

   ```
   const SomeComponent = () => {
     const ref = useRef([1, 2, 3])
     useEffect(() => {
       // do something with ref.current
     }, [ref])
   }
   ```
3. Finally, if the value of `a` is dynamic or dependent on props that may change over time, use `useMemo`. Be aware that `useMemo` is not a semantic guarantee—React may opt to eject stored values to free memory, and so it should only be used as a performance optimization:

   ```
   const SomeComponent = () => {
     const a = useMemo(() => [1, 2, 3], [])
     useEffect(() => {
       // do something with a
     }, [a])
   }
   ```